# Reduce the number of conditional operators (5) used in the expression (maximum allowed 3)

Tags: angularjs, sonarqube

I have the following condition in my angular application

```
   else if (((column.field === "ttUser" 1|| column.field === "ttAdmin") 2&& $scope.EngttAccess) 3|| ((column.field === "btUser" 4|| column.field === "btAdmin") 5&& $scope.EngbtAccess)) {
```

how can i make this to solve sonar qube issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should behave same way as your example.

```
else if (
    (["ttUser", "ttAdmin"].includes(column.field) && $scope.EngttAccess) ||
    (["btUser", "btAdmin"].includes(column.field) && $scope.EngbtAccess)) {
```

Comment: No, it shouldn't. `"ttUser" != "btUser"`. `"ttAdmin" != "btAdmin"`.

Comment: it's not checking 2nd condition

Comment: That's true. I failed to notice second block had "bt*" and not "tt*". Updated answer with a fix.

Comment: Slight performance benefit to putting the `includes` after the && rather than before, but if sonarqube allows one to turn off a rule on a particular line through comments (I don't know SonarQube) that would be better still. This isn't more readable, so it's the developer working for the tool instead of the tool working for the developer.